# ios: manage some viewcontroller in navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

In my app I need to manage a navigation controller and move it in these viewcontrollers, so I do it

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*) [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationcontroller"];
    [navController addChildViewController:firstViewController];
    [navController addChildViewController:secondViewController];
    [navController addChildViewController:thirdViewController];
    [navController addChildViewController:fourthViewController];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

first problem: navigation open at first fourthviewcontroller, why?

second problem: if from secondviewcontroller i do it to pass at first:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:self.navigationController.viewControllers[0] animated:NO];
```

I have a crash that say:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported
```

why? can you help me?

Comment: `UINavigationController` have property `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers`. Why not use it?

Comment: mmm ok I use it, but I have the same problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### First Problem

You're pushing four view controllers onto the navigation stack. So, your stack, after each step, looks like this:

```
[navController addChildViewController:firstViewController];
```

Stack: `firstViewController`

```
[navController addChildViewController:secondViewController];
```

Stack: `secondViewController`, `firstViewController`

```
[navController addChildViewController:thirdViewController];
```

Stack: `thirdViewController`, `secondViewController`, `firstViewController`

You can see the pattern here. In other words, the `fourthViewController` is presented because it's on the top of the stack.

#### Second Problem

As for your second problem, you can't push a view controller onto the stack that already exists in the stack. `[[self navigationController] pushViewController:self.navigationController.viewControllers[0] animated:NO];` seems absurd when you consider that fact. You're trying to push something from within the stack to the stack.

Comment: and to move to another viewcontroller? can I use pop?

Comment: You could push or pop depending on your needs. It's strange to push a bunch of view controllers in a row like that.

Answer (score 1):

**First question**

Every time you use "addChildViewController:", the new controller is added at the top of the stack. The last one inserted, your *fourthViewController*, is at the top of the stack, so it is shown when you call the method

```
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Second question**

It depends on the *pushViewController:* method itself. In the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController%3aanimated%3a) the doc said that:

> The viewController added cannot be an instance of tab bar controller and it **must not already be on the navigation stack**.

Your app crashes because *self.navigationController.viewControllers[0]* is already on navigation stack.